# Is there a hashing technique such that it would return the same hash for the reverse of a string as it would for the original string?

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

For example, this hash function should return the same hash value for both these strings.

String a = "hello"
String b = "olleh"

The motivation behind this is to find the duplicate pairs of words in a sentence.

Comment: Of course.  Any operation that is commutative will have this property -- for example addition, or XOR.

Comment: As will any algorithm in which you first apply the hash function f() to the original input x, then apply it to the reversed input, and perform some commutative operation (again, e.g. addition or XOR) to combine the two results.

Comment: Is it possible to not reverse the string at all and still get the same hashcode when the reverse of a string is the input for the hash function?

Comment: Yes -- see my first comment.

Comment: Can you give me an example. Didn't understand it straightaway.

Comment: If you add or XOR together the values of all the characters in the string, it doesn't matter in what order they appear.  So (in particular) you'll get the same value for "hello", "olleh", but also for "hlelo" and "eholl".

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I understoood and hence was confused. It will give me the same value if the same set of characters are used. This is definitely a good option, but not full proof. Thank you so much though. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome :)  Of course, addition and XOR are *very* weak hash functions ;)  BTW if your concern is about the memory allocation overhead of creating a reversed copy of the string to pass to the hash function, if you have access to the innards of the hash function you don't need to do that -- you can just run its loop in reverse, from the last character toward the first.,

Comment: *"The motivation behind this is to find the duplicate pairs of words in a sentence. "* - well, it won't work reliably, as hash functions can have collisions for different words.  At best it'd work as a kind of bloom filter to tell you when it can tell there's definitely no duplicate, but the rest of the time it won't know and you'll have to compare the text.  Better to put the strings you've seen - forwards and reversed (if different) - into a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`; you can test the `my_set.insert(x).second` return value - it'll be false if the word `x` is already in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we can generate hash function like this:

```
int hashCode(){
     int h = 0;
     if (h == 0 && value.length() > 0) {
        char val[] = value.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
             h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }

     }
     return h;
}
```

So, we can modify this a little bit, and obtained our hash function

```
 int hashCode(){
     int h = 0;
     if (h == 0 && value.length() > 0) {
        char val[] = value.toCharArray();
        int mid = value.length()/2;
        int rate = 1;
        if(value.length() % 2 == 0){
           mid = (value.length()*2 - 1)/2;
           rate = 2;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            h +=  val[i]*Math.pow(31, Math.abs(rate*i - mid));
        }

     }
     return h;
}
```

So, instead of using first character as the starting point to calculate hash code, we shift the starting point for calculate hash code to the middle character.

For even length string, we multiply all indexes by 2, so we can obtain an integer value for middle position.

Hash code for

```
hello: 213202
olleh: 213202
olelh: 213412
hlelo: 213412
```

**Update**:

We can observe that, for this above approach, two positions that symmetrical around the middle point will be considered equally, so, for example "hell" and "lelh" will have same hashcode.

<s>To avoid that, one way is to treat each half of the string as two separated strings, and combined their hashcode:</s>

```
   public int hashCode() {
        long h = 0;
        if (h == 0 && value.length() > 0) {
            char val[] = value.toCharArray();
            int mid = value.length() / 2;
            int rate = 1;
            if (value.length() % 2 == 0) {
                mid = (2*value.length() - 1)/2;
                rate = 2;
            }
            long midPart = 0;
            long lowerHalf = 0;
            long upperHalf = 0;
            if(value.length() % 2 != 0){
                midPart = val[value.length()/2];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < value.length()/2; i++){
                lowerHalf += Math.pow(31, mid - rate*i)*val[i];
            }
            for(int i = (value.length() + 1)/2; i < value.length(); i++){
                upperHalf += Math.pow(31,rate*i - mid)*val[i];
            }
            long max = Math.max(lowerHalf, upperHalf);
            long min = Math.min(lowerHalf, upperHalf);
            h = max*(long)Math.pow(31, (value.length() + 1)/2) + min + midPart;

        }
        return (int)h;
    }
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach! Works for most cases. Any reason you can think of for it to not work for two letter words? For example

    is:101020
    si: 110620

Comment: @VinayGaba thanks, updated my answer, the way `mid` calculated is not proper :)

Answer (score 5):

The construction `hash(min(string, reverse(string)))` ought to do the trick. This is an instance of a technique called [canonicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization).

Comment: Can I somehow skip the step where I have to reverse a string and still be able to find the result?